# Trim all beginning integers from start of a string using php

Tags: php, regex, string

here is my column `title`

```
132 lorem ipsum...
21-2 gold sky...
325/1 blue river...
420 health and food
right decision
... and so on.
```

So many titles begins with various integers and sometimes the integer is divided by `/` or `-`;

How can I trim all of them and get only alphabet part, i.e.:

```
lorem ipsum...
gold sky...
blue river...
health and food
right decision
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should take a look at [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace)

Comment: You should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `preg_replace` here to remove initials numbers, forward slash, or dash, followed by optional whitespace:

```
$input = "132 lorem ipsum...\n21-2 gold sky...\n325/1 blue river...\n100 420 health and food\nright decision";
$output = preg_replace("/(?<=^|\n)[0-9\/ -]+/", "", $input);
echo $output;

lorem ipsum...
gold sky...
blue river...
health and food
right decision
```

### Demo

Note this answer is robust to a line having more than one term containing numbers, e.g. `100 420 health and food` becomes `health and food`.

Comment: I think you forgot a `^`. Though really this should be closed as too broad. No effort was shown by OP.

Comment: @miken32 Actually, I was somewhat far off.  We can use a lookbehind to check for either the start of the string, or a newline.  If found, then we strip off numbers, slash, dash, or whitespace, in any amount.

Comment: For this case [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) is faster than preg_replace.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with `(^\d+)` as pattern.

```
$str = "123 Lorem Ipsum";
$cleared = preg_replace("(^\d+)", "", $str);
echo $cleared; //will echo Lorem Ipsum
```

Comment: note - this won't remove the `/` or `-` in OP's question - just ints

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, no I want to remove `all of them` till alphabet part beggins